# cmath build errors with VS2019 C++

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code that I can build with VS2015 and VS2017 but not with VS2019. I am getting build errors with cmath. I did a compare between the cmath file in VS2017 (MSVC 14.16.27023) and the cmath file in VS2019 (MSVC 14.29.30133) and there are many differences. As an example:

VS2017 cmath:

```
_Check_return_ inline float acos(_In float _Xx) noexcept
{
return (_CSTD acosf(_Xx));
}
```

VS2019 cmath:

```
_NODISCARD _Check_return inline float acos(_In float _Xx) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
return _CSTD acosf(_Xx);
}
```

I am getting the following errors for this line:
C2589: '(': illegal todken on right side of '::'
C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
C2059: syntax error: ')'

I am postulating that it may have something to do with the different parenthesis used between the two files. I also get this error for the asinf, atanf, atan2f, cosf, expf, fabsf, fmodf, logf, log10f, powf, sinf, sqrtf, and tanf.

Comment: So you're saying that an empty file with just `#include <cmath>` will fail to compile?

Comment: You didn't `#define` some macro beginning with an underscore (which are reserved identifiers), or did you?

Comment: This is obviously an issue with code you are not posting.  The first thing you should have done is what I mentioned in the previous comment -- create an empty C++ source file, and in it, just `#include <cmath>`.  If that source file compiles with no errors, then the issue is the code you are not showing.  Then the next thing is to incrementally add code to the empty C++ file, compile, etc. until you see the compilation give errors.  That means that the last item you added to the file is the cause of the issue.